# combine list to dict but don't kill duplicated

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to combine and change a list of tuples to `dict`. How do I add the qty together and show and the final result?

```
a = [(' E', ' 6'), (' F', ' 1'), (' A', ' 6'), (' F', ' 1')]

d = dict(a)
print(d)
```

I got this, my `F` is missing the qty:

```
{' E': ' 6', ' F': ' 1', ' A': ' 6'}
```

How do I make this output? `F` qty is missing:

```
{' E': ' 6', ' F': ' 2', ' A': ' 6'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
c = Counter(k for k, v in a for _ in range(int(v.strip())))
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict` that counts its inputs. If you want strings back, do

```
d = {k: f' {v}' for k, v in c}
```